# sshfs with fstab: wrong uid, gid and Input/output error

Tags: mount, fstab, sshfs

I want to sshfs from my Linux machine (Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS) to my MacBook. I could do it at command line with

`sshfs jczhang@10.0.2.2:/Users/jczhang/mysharedfolder  /home/jczhang/mysharedfolder`

It worked perfectly. Since I wanted to mount the shared folder automatically at boot time, I put this in /etc/fstab.

`jczhang@10.0.2.2:/Users/jczhang/mysharedfolder   /home/jczhang/mysharedfolder fuse.sshfs delay_connect,_netdev,user,uid=1000,gid=1000,IdentityFile=/home/jczhang/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other 0 0`

Here, 1000 is my uid and gid in Linux. After reboot, I found the directory was mounted but I could not access the directory.

```
ls -l
d?????????  ? ?       ?              ?            ? mysharedfolder/

cd mysharedfolder
-bash: cd: mysharedfolder: Input/output error

mount status had
jczhang@10.0.2.2:/Users/jczhang/mysharedfolder on /home/jczhang/mysharedfolder type fuse.sshfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,_netdev,user)
```

I did not know why sshfs kept using user_id=0,group_id=0. I tried different combinations of uid=1000,gid=1000 and idmap=user. None worked. I umounted the shared folder and did "mount -a". It still did not solve the problem.

I used the default SSHFS version 2.10. Later, I upgraded it to version 3.5.2. Nothing changed.

Does anyone know a solution? Thanks.

### UPDATE:

This problem drove me mad. Since this shared folder is for my personal use and sshfs works at command line, I find a workaround. In .bashrc, I put

`if ! [ -d /home/jczhang/mysharedfolder/flagfile ]; then
   sshfs jczhang@10.0.2.2:/Users/jczhang/mysharedfolder  /home/jczhang/mysharedfolder -o idmap=user,uid=1000,gid=1000
fi`

flagfile is a file to tell whether the folder is already mounted.
Every (first) time I login to Linux, the folder is automatically mounted for me.

It works great!

Comment: Here is what works for me: `
    stephen@nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn:/export/inbox   /mnt/inbox   fuse.sshfs nofail,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.requires=network-online.target,_netdev,user,idmap=user,transform_symlinks,identityfile=/home/stephen/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,default_permissions,uid=1000,gid=1000,exec 0 0`  This shows up as `user_id=0,group_id=0`. I don't know why, but maybe try this option string.

Comment: Tried but did not work. d???? disappeared this time and I have "drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root" It looked OK. But "cd mysharedfolder" gave "Too many levels of symbolic links". Also, mount showed a weird "systemd-1 on /home/jczhang/mysharedfolder type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=92,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=18368)"

Comment: This might be a good candidate for `autofs` - see for example [Autofs and sshfs – the perfect couple](http://www.tjansson.dk/2008/01/autofs-and-sshfs-the-perfect-couple/). You might want to look at the `mountpoint` function instead of your `flagfile`.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem. Problem turned out to be that the remote was not present in the local machine root's `known_hosts` file. Simply doing:

```
sudo mount /path/to/mount
```

will cause `sshfs` to prompt for addition of remote into root's `known_hosts` file - so if you choose yes at the prompt, it should be done.

Note the `sudo`. `mount` without `sudo` will mount it successfully, but will add the remote to the user's `known_hosts` file instead of the root's. `fstab` entries are mounted by root, so if you've not added the remote to the root's `known_hosts`, it won't find it and the mount will be incomplete, and results in the input/output error.

Comment: Thanks! I had a similar issue, but using mount didn't work - instead I used "sudo ssh user@host" to invoke the host prompt and add it in root's known hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

I have this exact setup working:

My OS as 18.04.2:

```
] lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

My SSHFS version:

```
] sshfs -V
SSHFS version 2.8
FUSE library version: 2.9.7
fusermount version: 2.9.7
using FUSE kernel interface version 7.19
```

Creating the base:

```
] sudo mkdir /path/to/mount
] sudo chown $USER: /path/to/mount
] sudo nano /etc/fstab
] ssh REMOTEUSER@HOSTNAME touch /path/to/share/testfile
```

/etc/fstab entry: (you can remove the port entry)

```
REMOTEUSER@HOSTNAME:/path/to/share /path/to/mount fuse.sshfs port=PORT,_netdev,follow_symlinks,identityfile=/home/LOCALUSER/.ssh/RSAKEY,allow_other,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

Testing mount:

```
] sudo mount -a
] mount | grep HOSTNAME
REMOTEUSER@HOSTNAME:/path/to/share on /path/to/mount type fuse.sshfs (rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,_netdev)
] ls -l /path/to/
...
drwxr-xr-x 1 LOCALUSER LOCALGROUP 4096 Jun 28 09:20 mount/
...
] ls -l /path/to/mount/testfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 samh samh 0 Jun 28 10:45 /path/to/mount/testfile
```